# How to pass in JSON type into YAML CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iot1click-placement.html#cfn-iot1click-placement-associateddevices

states that the property `AssociatedDevices` is a type JSON, but when I am writing the template in YAML

I have read a few responses here and have tried the following:

```
AssociatedDevices: "--arguments": '{"SecuityButtonTemplate": !Ref TestITPA.DeviceId}'   
PlacementName: "TestITPAPlacement"      
Attributes:  "--arguments": '{"--Location": TestITPALoc}'
```

(this fails to build)

and this:

```
  AssociatedDevices: '{"SecuityButtonTemplate": !Ref TestITPA.DeviceId}'   
  PlacementName: "TestITPAPlacement"
  Attributes:  '{"Location":"TestingLoc"}'
```

(this also fails to build)

I have even search github for YAML code referencing AssociatedDevices but not finding how people are actually doing this - can anyone help me shed some light ?

I lastly have tried this:

```
     AssociatedDevices: !Sub |
{
    SecuityButtonTemplate: !Ref TestITPA.DeviceId
}   
  PlacementName: "TestITPAPlacement"
  Attributes:  !Sub |
{
    Location: "testingLoc"
}
```

(this throws what seems to be an IDE error - the middle variable of PlacementName is not longer red like the others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
AssociatedDevices: !Sub '{"SecuityButtonTemplate": "${TestITPA.DeviceId}"}'  
PlacementName: "TestITPAPlacement"
Attributes: '{"Location":"TestingLoc"}'
```

Comment: Thanks I got it compiled and deployed in CloudFormation - got this generic error 
```The following resource(s) failed to create: [TestITPAPlacement].```

So this may be something I need to research more

Comment: I also got it working this way:
```AssociatedDevices: 
        SecuityButtonTemplate: !GetAtt TestITPA.DeviceId 
      PlacementName: "TestITPAPlacement"
      Attributes: 
        Location: "TestingLoc"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `ToJsonString` intrinsic function

You can use [`Fn::ToJsonString`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ToJsonString.html) intrinsic function to transform YAML to JSON.

Example:

```yaml
AssociatedDevices: !ToJsonString
  SecuityButtonTemplate: !GetAtt TestITPA.DeviceId 
PlacementName: TestITPAPlacement
Attributes: !ToJsonString
  Location: TestingLoc
```

It works with other intrinsic functions (such as `Ref`, `Sub`, etc) so you code can be written in full YAML with top readability.

Make sure to add the [`AWS::LanguageExtensions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-languageextension-transform.html) transform in your template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
```